# How to style placeholder text color for individual text field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, firefox

I would like to style placeholder text in different color for each text field.

The code from mozilla doc below will affect entire input tag.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3a-moz-placeholder

```
<style type="text/css">  
    input:-moz-placeholder {  
      color: green;  
    }  
</style>
```

I want to have different colors for each text field.

**HTML**

```
<input id="foo" type="text" placeholder="im green" />
<input id="foo2" type="text" placeholder="im red />
```

**jQuery**

I tried below but it will just set the color to the input text field itself not to the placeholder.

```
var elementId = "#foo2";
$(elementId + ":-moz-placeholder").css("color", "red");
```

I think my selector is not specified correctly though not sure how to set properly.

How do I style individual placeholder by element id using jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried... CSS classes by any chance?

```
<input class="green" id="foo" type="text" placeholder="im green" />
<input class="red" id="foo2" type="text" placeholder="im red />

<style type="text/css">  
    input.green:-moz-placeholder {  
      color: green;  
    }  
</style>
```

Comment: Sure, I think I wasn't clear but I would like to know how to set it using jQuery css()

Comment: one way I can think of is to add class combined with your suggestion. $(elementId).addClass("green");

Answer (score 2):

:-moz-placeholder is a pseudo class.

Pseudo classes are not part of the DOM, so jQuery can not directly edit anything about them.

An alternate approach would be to use classes to change colors, which is what Walkerneo suggested.

Take his code, and then use this to switch the class from green to red:

```
    $("input#foo").toggleClass('red').toggleClass('green');
```

Comment: No, it is a pseudo _class_ (like `:visited`). WebKit’s `::-webkit-input-placeholder` is a pseudo element (like `::before`). Just count the number of double colons. :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I edited my answer to correct the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to prepend a  block with jQuery:

```
    var $inlineStyleTemplate = $("" +
            "<style id='custom-menu-color'> " +
                ".navigation-md-lg > li > a, .header-right > ul > li > a,.header-right .fa-search {color: " + menuColor + "}" +
                "svg {fill: " + menuColor + "}" +
                "#search-search {border-color: " + menuColor + "}" +
                "#search-search::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: " + menuColor + "}" +
                "#search-search::-moz-placeholder { color: " + menuColor + "}" +
                "#search-search:-ms-input-placeholder { color: " + menuColor + "}" +
                "#search-search:-moz-placeholder { color: " + menuColor + "}" +
            "</style>"
        );

    $('head').prepend($inlineStyleTemplate);
```